# Converting an list to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list that is in the form of a dictionary to an actual dictionary.

This is for a webs scraping tool. I've tried removing to the single `''` and setting as a dictionary, but I am new to programming and I think my logic is off in some way.

My list is of the form

```
['"name":"jack"', '"address":"1234 College Ave"']
```

I am trying to convert general form to a dictionary of the form

```
{"name":"jack", "address":"1234 College Ave"}
```

Comment: how are you getting this input?

Comment: It is a list, although formatting makes it look not as such.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a string JSON representation then use `json.loads`.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = ['"name":"jack"', '"address":"1234 College Ave"']
>>> json.loads('{' + ', '.join(data) + '}')
{'name': 'jack', 'address': '1234 College Ave'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['"name":"jack"', '"address":"1234 College Ave"']
d = {elem.split(":")[0][1:-1]:elem.split(":")[1][1:-1] for elem in l}
print(d)
```

Comment: @JackBashford Why did you mark is as OK in Review but complain about the answer here?

Comment: Fails for `l = ['"na:me":"jack"']`

Comment: @Finomnis True.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to fix each individual string before passing it to json.loads.

```
inp = ['"name":"jack"', '"address":"1234 College Ave"']

import json

result = {}
for item in inp:
    result.update(json.loads("{" + item + "}"))

print(result)
{'name': 'jack', 'address': '1234 College Ave'}
```

However, ideally you should be getting data in a better format and not have to rely on manipulating the data before being able to use it. Fix this problem "upstream" if you can.